# Tableau Server automated requests to Snowflake

Tags: tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We noticed on our Snowflake database that there are some activities coming from the Tableau Server requesting the Snowflake database every hour. We do not understand where these activities come from. It should be by a person connected to a dashboard or from an extract running, but it does not seem to be any of the two options, there is no user connected during the night.

Comment: As you have been able to detect activities, presumably you are able to see with which Login they are run? If that's the case I would disable that Login in the evening so that either the person or the extract will fail to reach the target. You will then get a complaint from that person or a failure notification email from Tableau Server :-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We have resolved the issue.